# Leaflet: set min/maxZoom dynamically

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet v0.7 and there seem to be no setters for min/maxZoom on the map or tileLayer.

Is there any way to set these values dynamically?

Answer (score 38):

If you have your map initialized

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

then you can simply do:

```
map.options.minZoom = 12;
map.options.maxZoom = 14;
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zbbzLwx/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same after map initialisation:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

map.setMinZoom(12);
map.setMaxZoom(14);
```

Comment: This is preferable as it seems to set the state properly, e.g. dimming the - zoom button if needed, and ensuring the current zoom is within the new limit.